# issue with child application paths

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7

I created a new website in IIS called wbsite1. Then I added an application to website1 wich is a website called website2. The problem appeared when we tried to access links in website2. The browser always refers to the root url and redirect so we were trying to change all the urls in website2. For example, if we have a url in website2 like :

```
<a href='http://localhost:2030/website2/cms/default.aspx...'
```

and we click on that link the browser redirect us to :

```
http://localhost:2030/website1/default.aspx
```

Why am I getting this behavior? And what is the best workaround to integrate two websites without trying to mess with every link in the website? Thank you very much.

[image]

We are facing troubles *when* I try to access a page in the child application it redirects to the default page of the main application and gives the error:

> Session state is not available in this context.

Comment: could it be a Forms authentication element in website1 web.config, with loginUrl or defaultUrl redirecting to /website1/default.aspx, that is used/inherited in your website2 ?

Comment: no their is nothing like that in web.config of website1 nor website2

Comment: the problem reside in links used inside website2 and not website1

Comment: I am having some trouble understanding how EXACTLY are the applications structured - no offence, but your English skills could use some polish. Can you post a screenshot of your IIS structure?

Comment: does <a href='http://localhost:2030/website2/cms/default.aspx...' appears in the generated html source code?

Comment: Can you share the code-behind logic for `/website2/cms/default.aspx`?

Comment: Have you checked IIS for default Redirection of Browser Requests.
see http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/6b855a7a-0884-4508-ba95-079f38c77017.mspx?mfr=true . It may also be due to this reason.

Comment: the child application is a page containing an iframe and every request from other pages is loaded within that iframe is it may be the reason ?

Comment: Can you Run fiddler to check which page is loaded just before `.../website1/default.aspx` page. This will make clear that which page is causing redirection to `.../website1/default.aspx` page.

Comment: In your picture, is vivacms = website1 and cms = website2?

Comment: yes it is vivacms= website1 and cms=website2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution for my question and it's this :

```
 unfortunately i have to "rewrite" all our links in my code. 
 so  i created a function which will automatically add prefix to external links,
 and store base link for other site it configuration. 
 I did such project with success.  thank u for all your replies
```

i found another solution also and it's using a web proxy but i can't use it in my scenario